# Insert javascript into local html using its CSS stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css

Modifying a SnapPages theme, meaning I only have access to the CSS stylesheet. I would like to insert some javascript in the header of the site in order to use TypeKit for styling typography. Is there anyway to do that from CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

More complex answer: CSS doesn't have the ability to make any changes to your page and things included in a page either via:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />
// or
<style> 
  ..
</style>
```

Can't be made to execute as script.

Answer (score 1):

Though you can in a sense [alter (some of) the contents](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_gen_content.asp) of a page from CSS, its use is discouraged and [it is not up to the task you want to handle](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter_content.html).

[From quir]{smode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html):
"*I feel that we shouldn't use the content declaration at all. It adds content to the page, and CSS is meant for adding presentation to the page, and not content. Therefore I feel that you should use JavaScript if you want to dynamically generate content. CSS is the wrong tool for this job.*"

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, no.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is, no.

The only thing coming even close is IE-Based CSS Expressions (examples [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(VS.85).aspx)). It may even have been possible to import style sheets that way, but support was discontinued in IE8.